# Justification for Inverse Trigonometric Substitutions

Tags: calculus

Hi I am currently in calculus 2 and we are studying inverse trigonometric substitution. We were given this table[image: table]

However, I have no idea how these expressions were produced or where they were gotten from. Can someone please explain this to me? It was not explained to me by my teacher and I currently cannot find anything online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it was expressed to me like that I would be confused, to...

It all comes from the rule $\sin^2 t + \cos^2 t = 1$

and dividing through  by $\cos t$

$\tan^2 t + 1 = \sec^2 t$

In the examples above:

Substituting  $x = a\sin t$ into the expression $(a^2 - x^2)$

$(a^2 - x^2) = (a^2 - a^2\sin^2 t) = a^2(1-\sin^2 t) = a^2\cos^2 t$

Similarly, substituting $x = a\tan t$ into $(a^2 + x^2)$ gives $(a^2+a^2\tan^2 t) = a^2\sec^2 t$

The radical ($\sqrt{}$) doesn't have to be there for you to consider these substitutions.

For example:

$\int \frac {1}{1+x^2} dx$

As described above, that suggests applying the substitution:

$x = \tan t\\
dx = \sec^2 t\ dt$

$\int \frac {\sec^2 t}{1+\tan^2 t} dt\\
\int 1 \ dt\\
t + C$

Reverse the substitution.

$x = \tan t\\ t = \arctan x\\
\arctan x + C$

Another way to think about it.

Consider $y = \arcsin x$

What is the derivative?

$\sin y = x\\
\frac {d}{dx}(\sin y) = 1\\
\cos y \frac{dy}{dx} = 1\\
\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac {1}{\cos y}\\
\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac {1}{\cos (\arcsin x)}$

$\cos (\arcsin x) = \sqrt {1-x^2}$

$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac {1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$